# Programatically deleting items from cart leaves 'ghost' items;

Tags: checkout, cart, event-observer

I am using the observer `checkout_cart_save_after` to programatically delete some cart items.

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $cart = $observer->getCart();
    $quote = $cart->getQuote();
    $cartItems = $quote->getAllItems();

    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $cart->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();
    }
}
```

Whilst this does delete the cart items, it still shows the checkout page as an empty table like so:

[image: Programatically deleted cart]

But if I delete all the items manually on the frontend, I get a much nicer page after I delete the last item:

[image: Manually deleted cart]

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you need to clear cart instead of remove items. plz try https://magecomp.com/blog/programmatically-clear-shopping-cart-magento-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

Use the `checkout_cart_save_before` event, this way it will serve the correct cart page as well as handling calculating the totals correctly.

## Breakdown on why

The logic that decides what page you get served is in the following method `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart->getItemsCount()` which in turn calls `getItemsCount` on the quote.

If the method returns a truthy value, you will get served the cart with the sidebar otherwise you get the one without.

The `items_count` data property on the quote is only, with the exception of the dot mailer module, set when you collect totals for the quote in `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector->_collectItemsQtys()` which is fired from the `collect` method within the same class.

The order of execution for saving the cart is as follows: (removed unrelated bits for simplicity)

- Dispatch Event `checkout_cart_save_before`
- Set Billing/Shipping Address
- Collect Totals (Here `items_count` is set)
- Dispatch Event `checkout_cart_save_after`

So as you can see by using the `checkout_cart_save_after` event, your code is fired after the totals are collected. Meaning the cart totals/items count is still set as the values before you removed the items.

And I believe (don't quote me on this) where the totals on the cart are loaded with ajax, this recalls the method to collect the totals. Which then causes the ajax'd totals to pull the correct `items_count` and totals through. Although at this point its too late since the cart is already rendered.

## Solutions

Ideally, if you want to modify the items in the quote you would use the before event `checkout_cart_save_before` so when it calculates the shipping rates/totals if takes into account your changes.

Or you could recollect the totals after you've made your changes in the after event. `$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()`

Or you can manually update the `items_count` value on the quote after you remove an item from it like you are currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that for whatever reason, the item count for the quote object never hit 0. I ended up having to write some logic to update it at the end of the observe...

```
$quote->setItemsCount($quote->getItemsCount() - 1);
$quote->setItemsQty($quote->getItemsQty() - 1);
$quote->save();
```